# Vendor ID changes with app re-installation with iOS 11 GM

Tags: ios

I've just noticed that the vendor id is changing whenever the app in uninstalled and re-installed with iOS 11, but does not with iOS 10.

I can't find any reference to this being intentional behavior from Apple, but as this is occurring in the Gold Master of iOS 11 presumably it can't be a bug at this very late stage.

Anybody have any info of this?

[P.S. Yes I know it can be stored in the keychain]

Comment: Sorry but *"as this is occurring in the Gold Master of iOS 11 presumably it can't be a bug at this very late stage"* made me laugh. There are MANY bugs in iOS 11. It's only GM because the launch date has arrived, not because all bugs have been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
>   app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value
>   changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
>   device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can
>   also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing
>   an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app
>   stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully
>   handle situations where the identifier changes.